# UDP Hole punching unsuccessful, but tests show it should work (mobile network)

Tags: udp, nat, hole-punching

For the past two week I have been unsuccessfully trying to implement udp hole punching, but I'm not sure why. I understand that the algorithm for hole punching is not guaranteed to work, but I believe it should work in my test case because I have noticed that once I bind my socket on my home-network, the port is the same to the outside world as it is locally, and stays that way for all connections made from this socket. Any help after reviewing my trials would be appreciated.

I have three computers, my osx desktop, my iPhone, and my amazon ec2 ami.

on the desktop I've built a cocoa app which uses the GCDAsyncUDPSocket library to bind a port and contact the ec2 server, where a java app using apache's mina library stores the sockets external ip/port and associates it with a username passed in the payload.

the iphone, which is on the AT&T network runs an app which uses the same GCDAsyncUDPSocket library to contact the ec2 server with the same username, which then the ec2 does a lookup for the username, finds the desktops info and informs the desktop of the iphones address and the iphone of the desktops address.

now the iphone & the desktop know about each other they start shooting off packets at each other in hopes to get a punched hole.

in theory this should work, but maybe I am missing something about mobile networks that would make this difficult? But then again running a simple udp echoer on a 4th external computer to manually msg the desktop did not work either, so maybe its my router, but I don't see how that could be as all my tests show that the port the desktop asks for is the same one assigned by the router.

I've been at this for nearly two weeks with little progress and any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"once I bind my socket on my home-network, the port is the same to the outside world as it is locally"

I highly doubt that. To traverse NAT given peers A and B which have sent datagrams to a 3rd party: S you need to send datagrams from A to B and vice versa using their public IPs as seen by S *and their port as seen by S* (i.e. not the port A, B are bound to from their point of view).

Comment: This does not answer the question and should have been a comment.

Comment: It may or may not but it is one possible answer - that is the reason for it not working - I am saying the port as seen from the outside is not the same and emphasising he needs to take into account address _and port_.